# Using @types from specific folders with typescript

Tags: typescript, lerna, monorepo

We have a monorepo using Lerna, with package a and package b both containing @types/react.

Package A has Package B as a dependent so I end up with this:

Package A:
node_modules/PackageB/node_modules/@types

Which causes loads of duplicate errors.

We don't use any workspaces (as of yet) and we use NPM. When compiling with TSC (for type checking), it throws a load of errors about duplicate packages and missing packages.

I was hoping there might be a way with tsconfig to specify the types folder I want to use?
So instead of just grabbing all of them, it grabs only node_modules/@types rather than nested ones?

I've tried using typesRoot, types, and paths. All to no avail. Currently we're using skipLibCheck, but it's no ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each package should have a dependency on react types (don't use file paths!), [`lerna bootstrap`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/bootstrap) used with the [`--hoist` flag](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/bootstrap#--hoist-glob) will wire them up without duplication. You will probably want to also use the [`--strict` flag](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/bootstrap#--strict) which will ensure you keep the dependency versions in lockstep.